# How do I avoid lines at top and left borders of png files exported from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

When I export Illustrator artwork as a png file, I get a one pixel grey border at the top and left edges.

There is no background object, but I export (Save for Web and Devices) with matte white background and no transparency.  I also tried with a white background object, with it snapped to the artboard and also larger than the artboard by 10 pixels in each direction.  I still got the lines at the top and left of the exported image.

I also tried making a new file, with the artboard in pixel units, and selected the option to have objects snap to pixel grid, and then copying and pasting the artwork from the original file.  I still got the lines.

Comment: Can you post one of the files so we can take a look?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After much tearing of hair the following works for me:

1. Select **View > Pixel Preview**.
2. **View > Snap to Pixel** should be ticked.
3. You should use Artboards
4. The Artboards should be laid out by Illustrator not by you, so if you've created, copied or positioned any: **Objects > Artboards > Rearrange** and choose a whole pixel value for spacing. This will lay the artboards out to exact pixels.
5. Choose **View > Pixel Preview** and check the edges of the artwork for unwanted anti-aliasing. It sometimes helps to extend shapes beyond the edges of the artboard.
6. When you're happy with how it looks, choose **File > Export** and tick **Use Artboards**
7. Antialiasing type selection seems to have little effect on this issue but will effect the way your artwork looks.

Comment: I'd recommend using Slices rather than Artboards. Slices are always pixel boundary aligned, Artboards aren't.

Comment: @MarcEdwards Whilst this is true, unfortunately slices are way too fiddly and hard to use. Artboards are pixel aligned if you let Illustrator lay them out.

Comment: In my case, I must resize my artboard to have exact pixel size **BEFORE REARRANGING** them e.g. width =50, height =40 (not something like 40.3333). And for rectangles inside artboards, they must have integer value for x,y position and **ODD INTEGER** value for width and height (e.g. 171, 135, not 170, 134)

Comment: The ODD INTEGER is due to your x, y position being at the default anchor location (the center) of the rectangle.  Choose a different anchor location (e.g. bottom left) and your coordinates will turn even.

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you for tearing your hair out so I don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a duplicate question that was just closed, I'd say the problem is that your graphic is not pixel-aligned, so you have an anti-alias artifact showing up. Try creating a new document, turning on "Align New Objects to Pixel Grid," and recreate.

Comment: Unfortunately this is part of the solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, choosing "use Artboards" when exporting circumvents this situation.

Answer (score -2):

i had this same problem and realized i had set up my document with a bleed, so when i disabled bleeds and tried exporting again to PNG, i had no problem with white border showing up. click "use artboards" at export.